# Laravel 5.6 Reflection Exeption - Class App\Providers\App\Campaign does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, reflection

This thing has got me stumped.

I get this error/Reflection Exception -> **Class App\Providers\App\Campaign does not exist**

Campaign is a class created for the app.

What's weird is that this error only shows up when I use a "show" resource route. When I list it using the "index" route. I get no errors.

Here's the class:

---

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Campaign extends Model
{
protected $table='campaigns';
protected $primaryKey = 'campaignID';
protected $fillable = [
    'campaignID',
    'campaignName',
    'shortDescription',
    'longDescription',
];

public function company(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company','companyID','companyID');
}

    public function person(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Person','campaignID','campaignID');
    }
}
```

---

and here's the "show" function from the controller

---

```
public function show(Campaign $campaign)
{
    $campaign = Campaign::find($campaign->campaignID);
    return view('campaigns.show', ['campaign'=>$campaign]);
}
```

EDIT - here's the entire controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Campaign;
use App\User;
use App\Company;
use App\Lead;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class CampaignsController extends Controller
{
    /**
    * Display a listing of the resource.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
    */
    public function index()
    {
        $campaigns=Campaign::get();
        return view('campaigns.index', ['campaigns'=> $campaigns]);
    }

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
        return view('campaigns.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $coID = Auth::user()->companyID;
        $uID = Auth::user()->id;


        $campaign = Campaign::create([
            'campaignName' => $request->input('campaignName'),
            'shortDescription' => $request->input('shortDescription'),
            'longDescription' => $request->input('longDescription'),
        ]);


        if($campaign){
            $campaigns=Campaign::where('companyID',Auth::User()->companyID)->get();
            return view('campaigns.index', ['campaigns'=> $campaigns])
                ->with('success' , 'Campaign created successfully');
        }
        return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating new campaign');
    }    

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Campaign  $campaign
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */

public function show(Campaign $campaign)
{
    $campaign = Campaign::find($campaign->campaignID);
    return view('campaigns.show', ['campaign'=>$campaign]);
}
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\Campaign  $campaign
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(Campaign $campaign)
{
    $campaign = Campaign::find($campaign->campaignID)->toSQL();
    dd($campaign);
    return view('campaigns.edit', ['campaign'=>$campaign]);
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\Campaign  $campaign
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, Campaign $campaign)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  \App\Campaign  $campaign
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy(Campaign $campaign)
{
    //
}

public function listcompanycampaigns()
{
    $campaigns=Campaign::where('companyID',Auth::User()->companyID)->get();
    return view('campaigns.index', ['campaigns'=> $campaigns]);
}

public function listambassadorcampaigns()
{
    $campaigns = Campaign::get();
    return view('campaigns.ambassadorindex', ['campaigns'=> $campaigns]);
}
```

### }

I've already cleared the cache and "composer dump-autoload" to no avail.

Thanks for any help you guys can give.

Jeeves

Comment: You show the entire code of the controller

Comment: Do you have `use App\Providers\Campaign` in controller?

Comment: Notice that "App" appears twice in this namespace "App\Providers\App\Campaign".  Check all your namespaces.  Make sure that the controller's show() method is injecting App\Campaign and not just Campaign.

Comment: Yeah. That was the weird thing that the App showed twice. I already verified that App/Providers was  not in the controller.

I dont think it even makes it into the show function because I tried to add a break to show the resulting SQL and didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

What does your route look like? Are you using route model binding?

If you are, then you should learn how it works first:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-model-binding

Otherwise, remove the typehint in your `show` method and lookup the model with an actual integer in your find method.

Comment: Thanks for this. I thought that adding the model in the RouteServiceProvider would work. But still having that same problem. But your tip added some insight into what might have been going wrong.